# Flexunit testing a TweenMax that calls a function.

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, flexunit, gsap

How do I unit test the forexample() function to make sure that the function is called within the delayed time?

```
private var done : Boolean;

private function forexample():void
{
    done = false;
    TweenMax.delayedCall(3 , toBeCalledFunctionNane);
}

private function toBeCalledFunctionNane():void
{
    done  = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works I assure you, but if you want to see it yourself you can try this:

```
private var callRegistered : uint = 0;

private function forexample():void
{
    callRegistered = getTimer();
    TweenMax.delayedCall(3 , toBeCalledFunctionNane);
}

private function toBeCalledFunctionNane():void
{
    trace("Function was called after:", getTimer() - callRegistered);
}
```

This will trace out the time in which the function was called in milliseconds.

P.S. You'll have to add this import statement to use the `getTimer()` method:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is , I can't edit the code I'm testing. I only have access to a function that returns the variable done. So I can't write anything within the function toBeCalledFunctionNane().

Comment: Oh I understand. If you're using Flex you could try to use the `PropertyChangeEvent` to catch the change.